# Image and text side by side and centered?

Tags: html, position

I can not figure out how to get the title and subtitle to appear after the knight on the same line. Any help? I've tried div and tables too. It just refuses to be next to each other and centered.

[Chess Page](http://universitychessclub.org/gg.html)

The Full Code

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>University Chess Club</title>

</head>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("ChessBackground.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size : cover;
}
h1{
/*margin-left:23%;*/
font-size:350%;
color: #f2f0ea;/* --off- yellow-white-- */
margin-bottom:5px;
font-family: 'Voltaire', sans-serif;
}

h2{
margin-left:35%;
width:50%;
margin-top:0%;
color: #f2f0ea;/* --off- yellow-white-- */
font-family: 'Voltaire', sans-serif;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
overflow: auto;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.group {
overflow: auto;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.box-set {
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="box-set">
  <figure class="box"><img src="header.png" alt="Header" height=35% width=35%></figure>
<figure class="box"><h1>University Chess Club</h1><h2>At The University Of Utah</h2></figure>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is retarded, why is it so impossible to display an image and text next to each  other centered on a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

I made an example, maybe can help you a little: [Codepen: Image and text side by side and centered](http://codepen.io/yamitrvg12/pen/KzPrrR)

```css
body {
  background: url('http://hdwallpaperfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Fantasy-Knight-With-Sword-Computer-Desktop-Background-279525.jpg') no-repeat fixed center 0;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.holder {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box-set__knight {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.box-set__knight-image {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.box-set__header {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 0 0;
}

.box-set__header h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.box-set__header h1 span {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="box-set">
    <div class="box-set__knight"><img class="box-set__knight-image" src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/rij/G8e/rijG8eeBT.png" alt="knight icon" /></div>
    <div class="box-set__header">
      <h1>University Chess Club
        <span>University Chess Club</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I will try it when I get home. The text shows up under the image. Is it side by side for you?

Comment: I see the text under the icon. How can you put the icon next to the text?

Comment: In my example I used `display: inline-block;` but there are another ways, for example `float: left` on each element, `position: absolute;`

Comment: I tried float left, it puts the icon and text on edges, but I want them next to each other centered.

Comment: I updated the example that I have in codepain: [link] (http://codepen.io/yamitrvg12/pen/KzPrrR). I used on each block element the `float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

Use positioning

```
<img src="http://www.willmaster.com/images/wmlogo_icon.gif" 
   style="position:relative; left:100px; top:100px; width:50px; height:50px; border:none;"
   alt="fixed position Willmaster logo"
   title="Willmaster logo in fixed position" />
<span 
   style="position:relative; left:150px; top:75px; width:50px; height:50px; border:none;">
```

TEXT HERE